# Compilation Error The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, iis-7

I've recently been drafted onto a C# web based project.

I have a DLL file I wrote in C# that I'm trying to get working with a aspx page. It all works fine on my local machine. I upload the project to a 2008 server and get the following:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'GNVHandler' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line 6:  using
>   GNVHandler;

The contents of the site are:

- test.aspx
- test.aspx.cs
- Bin/GNVHandler.dll

The ASPX page is default as the aspx.cs apart from:

```
using GNVHandler;
```

and to test things are working:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GNVHandle GNV = new GNVHandle();
}
```

Now I've run:

> regasm.exe GNVHandler.dll

The result of this was:

> Types registered successfully

but still the error persists. Any help on this please?

Comment: Usually this would work if it is within the bin folder, the dll has copied over to the bin folder on the production server too?

Comment: For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx

Comment: Yes the folder structure is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue,

There were insufficient security privileges on the /Bin folder.

Problem solved!